# How to get current configurable product sku in controller - Magento 2

Tags: configurable-product, cart, extensions, magento-2.0.7

I am trying to get current product SKU in controller using the below code:

```
namespace Test\ProductsToCart\Controller\Product;

class Styles extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $data;
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $prid = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
        $pr1id = $prid->getSku();
        echo $pr1id;
    }
}
```

but couldn't get the result.

Is there any problem with this line of code?

```
 $prid = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
```

Also tried:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
echo $product->getId();
$product->getSku();
```

Getting error like:

> Call to a member function getId() on null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work fine, if the current product has already been registered in some other part of the code.

However, if you are sending a query to your Controller, and the product hasn't been registered yet, you'll get 'null' instead of the SKU value.

If you are sending an AJAX query from a product page, you can send a product ID in the parameters and get a product from the repo the following way:

```
/**
 * @var $this->productRepository \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
 * @var $productId int
 */
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
if ($product) {
    $sku = $product->getSku();
}
```